# How to make scanf stop reading from input based on the first char?

Tags: c, scanf

I am stuck with `scanf()`
Can somebody help me please and tell me how can I read the first character in `scanf()` and based on that character decide whether I want to read 1 or 2 or 3 inputs:
For example :
`scanf( char , int int int)` if character
S , how do I make it stop after input :

`S 45`

Comment: Use more than one scanf, the first scanf only reads 1 character, and you choose how many integer numbers to read in subsequent scanfs based on the character read.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, and to easier error recovery in general, you should read one line of input at a time with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[128];
    printf("Enter letter and values:\n");
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        if (*line == 'A') {
            int a, b, c;
            if (sscanf(line, "A %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
                printf("A code, a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
            } else {
                printf("A code requires 3 integers\n");
            }
        } else
        if (*line == 'S') {
            int a;
            if (sscanf(line, "S %d", &a) == 1) {
                printf("S code, a=%d\n", a);
            } else {
                printf("S code requires 1 integer\n");
            }
        } else
        {
            /* handle other input codes... */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```